# react-youtube get live playtime and set playtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, youtube-api

Currently I'm using the [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) in my react/redux application and its working great with the youtube API.

I have noticed you can get the current time with this function: `.getCurrentTime()` which is located in the javascript object you get from the player. But this function doesn't give me a live value of the playtime. It only updates on refreshes of a component in my application.

I'm using it like this in my component parameters:

```
playtime={this.props.player.youtubePlayer.getCurrentTime()}
```

Is it possible to get the current playtime live in my react application without using a `setTimeout` loop?

I was also wondering if its possible to set the current playtime of a youtube video with this API? There is no available function in the youtube object like `setVolume`.

Comment: what about `componentDidUpdate`? would that work?

Comment: Without using `setInterval` to fetch continually fetch the time, or some callback provided by the library, there's nothing to tell your component the value of `.getCurrentTime()` has changed and therefore should be updated.

Comment: Allright so the only solution is using a setinterval? It isn't possible to read the iframe html elements for example?

Comment: For the set current playtime, you could use seekTo method as stated here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo